# How to alter plot axes in seaborn scatterplot matrix, sns.pairplot()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, seaborn

I have the following plot with `sns.pairplot()`

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
sns.pairplot(df, hue="B")
```

[image]

The axes for `D` are terrible. How does one format this such that either one uses different values, or you space on the bunched-together values on the x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access an array of matplotlib `Axes` at the `.axes` attribute of the object that `pairplot` returns.